# como ocultar las rutas angular

Tags: angular, rutas, angular7, angular-material, router

tengo 2 componentes, inicio y descargas
y en el app-routing.module los tengo configurados de la siguiente manera:

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'inicio', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: 'descargas', component: DescargasComponent }
```

y cada que navego entre ellas me aparece en la ruta de mi navegador

```
http://localhost:4200/inicio o http://localhost:4200/descargas
```

quiero que aunque entre a inicio o a descargas la ruta siempre se muestre como

```
http://localhost:4200
```

alguna solución?

Comment: No implementes el enrutamiento. Coloca todos los componentes dentro del componente principal y muéstralos usando condiciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La unica manera que puedes lograr esto, es usando `{ skipLocationChange: true }` de [NavigationBehaviorOptions](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#navigationbehavioroptions).

Elimina la configuración de  `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'inicio', pathMatch: 'full' }`, en tu AppComponent u otro elemento padre inyecta el Router y realiza una navegación por defecto:

```
this.router.navigate(['/inicio'], {skipLocationChange: true})
//
this.router.navigate(['/descargas'], {skipLocationChange: true})
```

Cuando quieras navegar a cualquiera de estas dos rutas, siempre utiliza el código de arriba.